# Javascript giving error only on load

Tags: javascript

The following is the javascript I wrote in my js file:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
var p = document.getElementById('hello');
ele[0].innerHTML= p.innerHTML;
```

But it gives error that p is null.
But when I run the same commands in console, they work perfectly.
Can someone please help me figure this out.

Comment: The js file is included in the head of your html and not inside a `window.onload` function?

Comment: This might be because your code is running before DOM is rendered. Try calling on document.onload

Comment: We can't see your HTML (we can guess, but we might guess wrong). We can't see *where* your script runs vs. *when* the elements are created (we can guess, but we might guess wrong). Please include a (non-)working sample that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As users suggested, it's about if the DOM is rendered or not when you run JS. You have 2 options.

1. When you link the script in the `<head>`, make sure to wrap it in `onload`, see example below
2. When you link the script in the `<body>`, you don't need to wrap it in `onload`

   ```
   // example
   window.onload = function(){ // or better use window.addEventListener
    // do some stuff or paste your code here
   }
   ```